# Why I can access internet using Tor browser but not from any other browser?

Tags: networking, browser, internet-connection, ping, tor

I'm using internet through local reseller that uses [mikrotik](http://www.mikrotik.com/) server.
Some times like now I can browse internet using [Tor browser](https://www.torproject.org/) but not from any other browser.

**I want to know why may that happen ?**

some ping results

```
C:\>ping 4.2.2.2
Pinging 4.2.2.2 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 4.2.2.2: bytes=32 time=125ms TTL=55

C:\>ping www.google.com
Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name and try again.
```

Comment: my guess you need to setup the proxy server settings.  Most browsers out of the box use the OS settings.  TOR browser since itself uses a proxy does not

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you unchecked all proxy settings:

[image: LAN setting]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your machine is having trouble resolving the name (DNS) for google.com into its IP address.  I would double-check your DNS configuration and make sure you're using valid DNS servers.